# What was the restaurant in New York shown at the end of "The Other Woman"

Tags: the-other-woman

What restaurant did the girls meet up in, in New York, at the end of the movie The Other Woman?

Comment: Why was it down voted ?

Comment: @Ankit My guess (I did not D/V) is that it is because the question is asking to ID a restaurant, and not involving the creation or choices used in making the movie. "Why was the restaurant that was used in the final celebration in The Other Woman scene chosen?" would be an on-topic question. "What is the restaurant shown in The Other Woman?" is off topic, as the question is ID a restaurant, which might be better asked in someplace like Travel:SE. How is the question, as asked, on topic for *this* SE?

Comment: I would add that while Napoleon Wilson was the culprit who removed the words "the movie -" from the original question, simply adding those two words back in does not make it an on topic question, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be the [Isola](https://thetake.com/location/4844/isola-trattoria-crudo-bar-new-york-ny-the-other-woman) as stated by Freddie. [This blog](http://thescript.thetake.com/isola-restaurant-the-other-woman/) discusses the restaurant and has pictures of the scene.

Final Restaurant celebration scene
[image: Final celebration scene]

Isola Restaurant
[image: Isola]

Answer (score 0):

It's the Isola Trattoria & Crudo Bar in new york

Comment: Can you back this up with a picture or a reference?